# Python 3: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='PATH_OF_FILE'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

When I run the test cases in python with *"python normalizer/setup.py test
"*  I am getting the below exception

```
 ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/workspace/aiworkspace/skillset-normalization-engine/normalizer/lib/resources/skills.taxonomy' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
```

In code I am reading a big file like below:

```
def read_data_from_file(input_file):
    current_dir = os.path.realpath(
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    file_full_path = current_dir+input_file
    data = open(file_full_path,encoding="utf-8")
    return data
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not closing the file.  You might look into the `with` statement ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Python unclosed resource: is it safe to delete the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057942/python-unclosed-resource-is-it-safe-to-delete-the-file)

> This ResourceWarning means that you opened a file, used it, but then forgot to close the file. Python closes it for you when it notices that the file object is dead, but this only occurs after some unknown time has elapsed.

```
def read_data_from_file(input_file):
    current_dir = os.path.realpath(
        os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    file_full_path = current_dir+input_file
    with open(file_full_path, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return data
```