# ResourceWarning for a file that is unclosed but UnitTest is throwing it

Tags: python, unit-testing, tracemalloc

I have a function like this:

```
def init_cars(self, directory=''):
    #some_code
    cars = set([line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(directory + "../myfolder/all_cars.txt")])
    #some_more_code
```

I am writing unittest and when I run them, I get the following error:

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='../myfolder/all_cars.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
  names = set([line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(directory + "../myfolder/all_cars.txt")])
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Found an answer but can't apply to my code that I can work out: [Python 3: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='PATH_OF_FILE'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752791/python-3-resourcewarning-unclosed-file-io-textiowrapper-name-path-of-file)

I tried a few things, made some code changes but can't seem to figure out. 
**Can anyone give me a code example on how to overcome this using my example code please!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not automatically close a filehandle for you when it is no longer referenced. This is surprising. For example.

```
def foo():
    f = open("/etc/passwd")
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

This will result in a ResourceWarning even though `f` is no longer available once foo() returns.

The solution is to explicitly close the file.

```
fh = open(directory + "../myfolder/all_cars.txt")
cars = set([line.rstrip('\n') for line in fh]
fh.close()
```

Or use [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) which will close the file for you.

```
with open(directory + "../myfolder/all_cars.txt") as fh:
  cars = set([line.rstrip('\n') for line in fh]
```